# How to use Serial Monitor without Arduino board?

Tags: serial

I want to use Arduino(atmega8) on breadboard using USBASP programmer and want to use Serial Monitor without using any Arduino board as ISP programmer.
My questions: 1. Is such thing possible?
2. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> How to use Serial Monitor without Arduino board?

Yes that is possible. Connect to the RX/TX pins on the breadboard chip. Remember these are 5V. You will need an Serial-USB or RS232 adapter to connect your development machine. Please see this [blog post](http://cosa-arduino.blogspot.se/2013/04/programming-attinyx5.html) for some inspiration.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't forget to also connect GND.

Comment: I stripped a USB cable and connected its green wire to RX and white wire to TX and red/black to supply pins of atmega8. But my PC is not detecting anything. (Atmega8 contains a arduino bootloader burnt using AVRDUDE and a basic analog to serial program. Please suggest where I am wrong.